# Best Practice - Electron - Efficiently switch platforms to publish electron app for each release?

Tags: javascript, electron, cross-platform, electron-forge

I have an electron app ready to distribute on Mac Os but I've given up trying to export the windows version on the Mac Os platform. I've read the various docs that say you can use wine or mono but I haven't had any luck and I see others struggle with this as well.

I'm installing bootcamp on my mac and I'm asking:
What is the most efficient way to move back and forth between platforms utilizing the same source code?

Can I share package.json and package-lock.json files or should I create new ones based on the information of the mac ones?

I assume all dependencies need to be reinstalled, but is there a list I can export showing me all the dependencies I have? (I have some dependencies required in the various JS files and not listed in package.json(ex:Firebase))

I know how I can manually rebuild the app in Windows but with each new release being exported on separate platforms I'd like to find a process for keeping both updated (or at least at time of export).

Thanks for any advice everyone!

Comment: I have been able to build Windows versions on macOS using either `electron packager` or `electron builder` (which I think uses the former). I do use Windows (running in emulation in VMWare Fusion) to code sign the .exe. I'd suggest not giving up instead of trying to maintain two build systems for the same project. Do you have native modules or some other complexity which is causing errors?

Comment: I know it uses electron-packager but one of the issues I get when exporting on Mac OS is that in all of my JS code it errors out when it reads any '...' object operators among some other JS code. I know the code is fine, I've run the plain zip file on both mac and PC okay. It seems like it doesn't like it when parsing for windows.

Comment: That seems like the question to try to answer instead of seeking some laborious workaround. And I'm not JS/Electron  hero but I don't see why `electron packager` would care about the contents of the JS files – it's not doing more than bundling them, afaik – unless you have some unusual setup. Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same situation a while ago, I ended up setting up a docker image as specified in https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build.html.

In my case I am using webpack so I isolate files in volumes for the following:

- Npm dependencies (node_modules)
- Webpack bundle

package-lock.json gets changed but so far I haven't got any problems, I create a npm script called publish-windows that calls docker run.

Comment: Are you running OS X Catalina 10.15 or higher? To my understanding wine no longer supports Mac OS X above 10.15.

Comment: @sychordCoder, wine is not being execute on OSX, it runs on a docker container. This is the image electron build recommends: https://hub.docker.com/layers/electronuserland/builder/wine-mono/images/sha256-a623432c159a02019e77a71873dfc6d4bf45f4b2011b333dbca429f02ee4cc56?context=explore